# How can I stop execution of JavaScript interval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a function with in setIntervel(), and I want to stop the execution of this function explicitly.How I can do this ???The function is..

```
function autoLoad(chatboxtitle, msgId) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (msgId != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../WebService1.asmx/GetMessagesDetail",
                data: '{ "messageID": "' + msgId + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#chatbox_" + chatboxtitle + ".chatboxcontent").empty();
                    $("#chatbox_" + chatboxtitle + ".chatboxcontent").append(msg.d);
                    $contentLoadTriggered = false;
                },
                error: function(x, e) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
    }, 8000);
}
```

Comment: Store the return of `setInterval()` into a variable, and call `clearInterval()` on it.

Comment: Further to what Michael said, did you consider reading some [`setInterval()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)?

Answer (score 10):

If you mean exit the function but not stop the interval (so the function will fire again) you need to simply `return` from the function.

If you mean stop the interval, i.e. stop the function ever firing again, you need to assign a reference to the interval in a variable and then clear it when/as required.

```
var intie = setInterval(function() { alert('hello'); }, 5000);
clearInterval(intie);
```